# Array/Pointer confusion

Tags: c++

Why does the following code print out `"0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "`? I was expecting `"1 3 6 10 15 21 28 "`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void PrefixSum(float * input, float * output, int n){
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        float value = input[i];
        sum += value;
        output[n] = sum;
    }    
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    float input[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    float output[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    PrefixSum(input, output, 7);
    for (int i=0;i<7;i++){
        cout << output[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: should be `output[i]`. **Debugger can help you a lot** in cases like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change `output[n]` to `output[i]` instead, you're not writing to any index in the array since `output[7]` is out of bounds. `i` is your loop counter not `n`

Answer (score 4):

change

```
output[n] = sum;
```

to

```
output[i] = sum;
```

Answer (score 4):

As everyone's pointed out, you're using `n` as the index instead of `i`, so you never modify any value within the array.

Writing loops is error prone, many of us will have made mistakes over the years. It's better to reuse existing code.

You're calculating the [`partial_sum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum). Using the standard library you could code it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    using std::partial_sum;
    using std::cout;

    const int SIZE = 7;
    float input[SIZE] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    float output[SIZE] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    partial_sum(input, input+SIZE, output);

    for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        cout << output[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

We can eliminate the loop printing out the result too:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//...

using std::copy;
using std::ostream_iterator;

copy(output, output+SIZE,
     ostream_iterator<float>(cout, " "));
```

And, finally, if you don't need the intermediate results array, we can just put the results straight to the `ostream` instead:

```
partial_sum(input, input+SIZE,
            ostream_iterator<float>(cout, " "));
```

Answer (score 3):

`output[n] = sum;`, `n` is `7` is out of `output` array boundary and you write data to it every time. Note, this is also undefined behavior.  You are accessing `float value = input[i];` right in for loop,  so I guess that's just a typo.

update

```
output[n] = sum;
```

to

```
output[i] = sum;
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the 'n' with the 'i' in your for-iteration in PrefixSum ;)